Could this surprise winning of a huge sum of money be legit?
I received a call from someone claiming to be from a well-known Cashback Coupon Co. He congratulated me and told me I had been selected to receive several thousand dollars a week for life. I was then told that I was required to pay more than a thousand dollars for insurance before they could issue a check for such a large amount. I paid it. Then he informed me that I had to pay a pre-tax of $8,000 before they could give me the prize money. The whole thing felt too strange to continue, so I pulled the plug and asked for a refund. It remains to be seen if I get it.

SCAM. Nobody who will really give you money will ask for a payment; they could deduct it from what they would be sending you. Any money or information you have given them is already lost. If you gave them any account information report that **immediately **to the bank or you may lose much more. In general, if you have to ask "is this a scam" the answer is "yes".

Does this answer your question? I was asked for a COT code to transfer money to my account. Is this a scam?

The moment they want you to pay money to get "your" money, is the moment you know it is a scam. Why did they need you to pay money for an insurance policy?

so I pulled the plug and asked for a refund. It remains to be seen if
I get it.

The goal was to get you to pay ever increasing amounts of money. They were only partially successful since they only took $1,000 from you.
They will not refund your money.
No group picks random people to win large sums of money.

The moment they say "I'm from well-known Cashback Coupon Co." and/or "Congratulations! You have won ..." is the moment you know it is a scam.

Even if it's Publisher's Clearinghouse or another legitimate sweepstakes that you actually entered, for big prizes they will want to show up on your doorstep with a camera crew to capture your delighted reaction; they won't just email you.

No genuine lottery will ever ask you for money. Say you win £1,000,000 in the UK lottery. And because you live in a foreign country with strange tax laws £200,000 has to be paid to your tax office. Plus a £500 bank transfer fee. In that case the lottery will pay the £200,000 tax, the £500 fee, and send you £799,500. There is absolutely no way they will ask you for money.

Or they will pay you the whole thing minus the transfer fee and tell you to reconcile taxes with the appropriate government agencies. Either way, you are not sending them money.

Pedantic quibble: you need to be located in the UK when buying National Lottery tickets (although, I believe, other members of a syndicate can be overseas).

@TripeHound - yes, and also the UK lottery operator will never contact a winner - anyone at all who is over 18 can buy a ticket in a shop using cash. The holder of a winning ticket has to claim the prize and it is paid with no deductions. If the prize is £50,000 or more, they will offer to send a representative to your house with a wad of cash, but only if you accept the offer.  If a valid claim is not received within 180 days of the draw date, the prize and any interest earned on it (accrued from the day of the draw) will go to benefit National Lottery charitable projects across the UK..
